# Remove extra white space when text overflows, while keeping text clamped to 2 lines max

Tags: html, css

When text overflows, it sizes the parent component to max width and takes up the remaining white space even after it overflows.
I'm trying to figure out a way of overflowing text WHILE keeping it clamped down to 2 lines and growing/shrinking the parent component to minimize white space as much as possible.

I was able to grow/shrink with a flex-box, but then can't clamp it down to 2 lines.

Here's a codepen of how far I've gotten https://codepen.io/illyabalakin/pen/KKGNvbY

```css
.btn {
  max-width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: min-content;
}

span {
  display: -webkit-box;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <span>Extended Text Overflowing overflow</span>
</button>

<button class="btn">
  <span class="flex">Extended Text Overflowing overflow</span>
</button>
```

[Image showing the empty space I want to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s3v2.png)

Comment: Do you have a visual of how you want it to look like? I am a bit confused by your question.

Comment: Is the empty space above the second button what you are trying to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {
  max-width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: wrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <span>Extended Text Overflowing overflow</span>
</button>

<button class="btn flex">
  <span>Extended Text Overflowing overflow</span>
</button>
```

Comment: that works here in stack overflow, but in my dev env and in the codepen,  it doesn't clamp to two lines it shows ellipsis on the first line

Comment: Have you changed the class to the parent element? I moved "flex" to the parent element & added a break after "Text"

Comment: The break wouldn't really work for my scenario - hoping for a more dynamic solution

Comment: I have updated now without the break in the HTML

Comment: @IllyaB. updated to be dynamic

Comment: that still leaves space on the sides of the button - I linked an image in the original post (bottom) of the space on the sides I'm trying to remove